# Create PDF with signature option

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, acrobat-pro-dc

I have pdf document with some forms that needed to be filled and signed. I's possible to create a pdf document that after filled and signed is sent to an specific email?

I have tried pandadoc service but the way they work is by me uploading the document and then send the document to a person. I want to have the pdf document on a site so people can sign it and then be emailed to me.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you have a digital signature, you can digitally sign the document, then email the signed document yourself.

Comment: Have a document be sent automatically means pdf reader has access to email app on the computer where signature is added. I don't think your clients would be happy with the idea.